# Search results in predictive search plugin

Tags: search, woocommerce

I am using the predictive search plugin to search/show my products for my woocommerce website.The results page shows the products each product one row.I would like to show them for example 3 products each row.I tried

```
.ps_list_items_container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#ps_list_items_container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
}
#ps_list_items_container > div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
}
```

as well as other css solutions but i cant make it work.
Does anyone know why?
Thanks a lot!